# Java-Regular Expression to match one backslah

Tags: java, regex

Hi I am trying to do a regular expresion that match one and only one time "\" so I can detect one directory level this example not work I don't know very  regular expresion  in Java.

```java
    String  input="C:\\andres\\an";
//    String  input="C:\\andres";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\{1}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("La cadena SI contiene un caracter \\");
        System.out.println(input);
    }else {
        System.out.println("La cadena no contiene un caracter \\");
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily using a negated character class regex:

```
^[^\\]*\\[^\\]*$
```

In Java regex string would be:

```
final String regex = "^[^\\\\]*\\\\[^\\\\]*$";
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GveGoc/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[^\\]*`: Match 0 more of any characters that are not `\`
- `\\`: Match a single `\`
- `[^\\]*`: Match 0 more of any characters that are not `\`
- `$`: End

**PS:** If you're using this regex in `.matches()` method then anchors `^` and `$` are not needed and you can just use:

```
final String regex = "[^\\\\]*\\\\[^\\\\]*";
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use this pattern:

```
^(?!.*\\.*\\).*\\.*$
```

This regex asserts that two (or more) backslashes do *not* appear.  Then, it goes on to match a single backslash.  In Java code:

```
String input = "C:\\andres";
if (input.matches("(?!.*\\\\.*\\\\).*\\\\.*")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

But, `String#split` might offer an even easier way of doing this:

```
String input = "C:\\andres";
if (input.split("\\\\").length == 2) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

A matching path, with only one backslash, when split on backslash should have exactly two resulting terms.